# Update MySQL query by foreign column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables named members and orders.

Members table
[image: Members columns]

Orders table
[image: Orders columns]
In my php codes, I wanted to update the columns in Orders table based on members_id which is a foreign key for members' id table.

This is how I put it:

```
$query = "UPDATE orders 
          SET package='$package', comments='$comments', refno='$refno', status='no'
          WHERE members_id.username='$username'";
```

I'm stuck at the WHERE query part.

Comment: Did you try the MySQL docs: [Update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) and [Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: I certainly hope you are sanitizing those variables before applying them to your SQL, Bobby Tables...

Answer (score 5):

If you need to update the order based on a *username*, you need to `JOIN` the members table:

```
UPDATE orders o
  INNER JOIN members m ON m.id = o.member_id
  SET o.package='$package', o.comments='$comments', o.refno='$refno', o.status='no'
  WHERE m.username='$username'
```

OR alternatively, first fetch the appropriate member id - `SELECT id FROM members WHERE username=...` and then use it in update query.

PS: Do not forget to escape all the values you place inside the query.

Comment: I may not be the brightest, but how to escape the values? And why? Thanks anyway for the queries. Much appreciated.

Comment: use `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['something'])` to prevent mysql injection

Comment: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection) is an attack technique used to inject arbitrary database queries into a victim database server via a website connected to it...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE orders o
INNER JOIN members m
ON o.member_id = m.id
SET package='$package', 
    comments='$comments', 
    refno='$refno', status='no' 
WHERE members_id.username='$username'
```

You should protect your query from sql injection using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or any other way to sanitize your parameters, see this excellent post here in SO for more details about sql injection and how to prevent it: [**Best way to prevent SQL Injection in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "UPDATE orders SET package='$package', comments='$comments', refno='$refno', status='no' WHERE members_id=(select member_id from members where username='$username')";
```

Normally you should use primary key (member_id) not username in your php/sql code to identify record. This will make risk of SQL injections lower, help to avoid problems when username is not unique, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The correct query will be:

```
$query = "";

$query .= "UPDATE orders";
$query .= "SET  package='$package'";
$query .= ",comments='$comments'";
$query .= ",refno='$refno'";
$query .= ",status='no'";
$query .= "WHERE members_id=(";
$query .= "    SELECT id FROM members WHERE username='$username'";
$query .= ")";
```